# redirection issue while integrating Facebook app in my iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, xcode5

i have created an iOS app in which i want Facebook integration for the user to get into my app for use. so i have done all the settings by going through the "developer.facebook.com"
    site and following all the steps. but in my app Facebook login works great.but after successful login  the app return on same login page from where i started but i want my app return to a new view controller after authentication. so i did  follow below code:

```
- (void)loginViewFetchedUserInfo:(FBLoginView *)loginView
                           user:(id<FBGraphUser>)user {
   [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"authentication" sender:self];
}
```

in my very first view controller file so that after authentication it move to my wanted view controller. it move to my desired view controller but after stay on my first view controller for a while and then move to desired one.but i don't want this senario.I just want that after authentication control move directly to desired one without display my first view controller that contain Facebook login button.
    please help me on this ,i stuck over this problem since many days.so any help would be appreciated.
    for your knowledge i am using plain view controller and not navigation controller. and i have checked my bundle id and url scheme many times and are correct.

Answer (score 0):

In loginViewShowingLoggedInUser method dissmiss the currentViewcontroller i.e one with fbloginview button..